# Cloudflare users ip issue on phpbb

Tags: php, cloudflare, phpbb, phpbb3

I cannot get this IP fix to work with my forum:

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200170746-How-do-I-restore-original-visitor-IP-with-PHPBB-

what else can I do to fix this issue with the IP for phpBB board?

Comment: Explain what went wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the extension from here: http://www.sitesplat.com/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=3200 for phpBB 3.1.x (Min v. 3.1.10) and higher, included the recently released phpBB 3.2.0

**How to Install a phpBB extension:**

Download and unzip the current release.
Copy the unzipped folder to the ext directory in the root of your forum. Note, if a phpbb directory already exists in your ext directory, do not overwrite it; just copy the extension-name folder to ext/vendor/extension.
Navigate in the ACP to Customise -> Manage extensions.
Look for extension-name under the Disabled Extensions list, and click its Enable link.

**How to Update a phpBB extension:**

Download and unzip the current release.
Navigate in the ACP to Customise -> Manage extensions.
Look for extension-name under the Extensions list, and click its Disable link.
Delete the old extension directory at ext/vendor/extension from your server.
Upload the new extension directory to ext/vendor/extension on your server.
Back in the ACP, click the Enable link.

**How to Uninstall a phpBB extension:**

Navigate in the ACP to Customise -> Manage extensions.
Look for extension-name under the Enabled Extensions list, and click its Disable link.
To permanently uninstall, click Delete Data and then delete the extension directory from your server.

Comment: not a word on how to install this extention.. would be really helpfull if someone could explain it.

Comment: You can install this extension juts as any phpBB extension that follow a proper code standards. I updated the post for you.

Comment: Thats awesome! Thank you very much :)